# Grouping 2 levels of a factor in R

Tags: r

I have a column of data that is a factor with levels A, B and C, I am interested in combining two of these levels into one factor, so it would become A and B, with B = B and C, or maybe a new variable A and D, with D = B and C. I can come up with plenty of ways to do this by looping through the column with if statements, but I feel like there should be a more elegant approach and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: More recent, better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410108/cleaning-up-factor-levels-collapsing-multiple-levels-labels

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use `levels(x) <- ...` to specify new levels, and to combine some previous levels.  For example:

```
f <- factor(LETTERS[c(1:3, 3:1)])
f
[1] A B C C B A
Levels: A B C
```

Now combine "A" and "B" into a single level:

```
levels(f) <- c("A", "A", "C")
f
[1] A A C C A A
Levels: A C
```

Comment: As simple as I could have hoped for, thank you!

Comment: Is there a way of doing this in dplyr?

Comment: What if I have say 100 levels (0,1,2,3.... 99) and I want to get only 3 (0, 1, biggerthan1) ?

Comment: @Hatshepsut use `levels<-`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449366/levels-what-sorcery-is-this/10491881#10491881

Answer (score 23):

If you're using `dplyr` pipes you can use the `forcats` package.

```
library(forcats)
f %>% fct_collapse(A = c("A","B"))

#[1] A A C C A A
#Levels: A C
```

Answer (score 4):

The rockchalk library is able to combine levels. I think its great, if you want to combine B and C together in a factor do this:

```
library(rockchalk)
combineLevels(mydf$facVar,levs = c("B", "C"), newLabel = c("BandC") )
```