# `levels<-`( What sorcery is this?

Tags: r, types, levels

In an answer to another question, @Marek posted the following solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432263/636656

```
dat <- structure(list(product = c(11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 11L, 5L, 
                                  7L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 8L)), .Names = "product", row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

`levels<-`(
  factor(dat$product),
  list(Tylenol=1:3, Advil=4:6, Bayer=7:9, Generic=10:12)
  )
```

Which produces as output:

```
 [1] Generic Generic Bayer   Bayer   Advil   Tylenol Generic Advil   Bayer   Generic Advil   Generic Advil   Tylenol
[15] Generic Bayer   Generic Advil   Bayer   Bayer
```

This is just the printout of a vector; so to store it, you can do the even more confusing:

```
res <- `levels<-`(
  factor(dat$product),
  list(Tylenol=1:3, Advil=4:6, Bayer=7:9, Generic=10:12)
  )
```

Clearly this is some kind of call to the levels function, but I have no idea what's being done here. What is the term for this kind of sorcery, and how do I increase my magical ability in this domain?

Comment: There is also `names<-` and `[<-`.

Comment: Also, I wondered about this on the other question but didn't ask: is there any reason for the `structure(...)` construct instead of just `data.frame(product = c(11L, 11L, ..., 8L))`? (If there's some magic happening there, I'd like to wield it too!)

Comment: It's a call to the `"levels<-"` function: `function (x, value)  .Primitive("levels<-")`, sort of like `X %in% Y` is an abbreviation for `"%in%"(X, Y)`.

Comment: @dbaupp I just used `dput` to output an object I'd created by subsetting my actual data, and `dput` returns `structure` calls by default.

Comment: @gsk3, Cool, didn't know about `dput`, thanks!

Comment: @dbaupp Very handy for reproducible examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I have no idea why someone voted to close this as not constructive? The Q has a very clear answer: what is the meaning of the syntax used in the example and how does this work in R?

Comment: Still shocked at how good all the answers are.  Thanks everyone.  Learned a lot.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11563358/636656

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The answers here are good, but they are missing an important point. Let me try and describe it.

R is a functional language and does not like to mutate its objects. But it does allow assignment statements, using replacement functions:

```
levels(x) <- y
```

is equivalent to

```
x <- `levels<-`(x, y)
```

The trick is, this rewriting is done by `<-`; it is not done by `levels<-`. `levels<-` is just a regular function that takes an input and gives an output; it does not mutate anything.

One consequence of that is that, according to the above rule, `<-` must be recursive:

```
levels(x)[1] <- "a"
```

is

```
levels(x) <- `[<-`(levels(x), 1, "a")
```

is

```
x <- `levels<-`(x, `[<-`(levels(x), 1, "a"))
```

It's kind of beautiful that this pure-functional transformation (up until the very end, where the assignment happens) is equivalent to what an assignment would be in an imperative language. This construct in functional languages is called a [*lens*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lenses_and_functional_references). Lenses can be awkward to use in some programming languages, but in R they just work.

But then, once you have defined replacement functions like `levels<-`, you get another, unexpected windfall: you don't just have the ability to make assignments, you have a handy function that takes in a factor, and gives out another factor with different levels. There's really nothing "assignment" about it!

So, the code you're describing is just making use of this other interpretation of `levels<-`. I admit that the name `levels<-` is a little confusing because it suggests an assignment, but this is not what is going on. The code is simply setting up a sort of pipeline:

- Start with `dat$product`
- Convert it to a factor
- Change the levels
- Store that in `res`

Personally, I think that line of code is beautiful ;)

Comment: For completeness, this is also described (somewhat formally) in the R language definition: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment

Answer (score 34):

No sorcery, that's just how (sub)assignment functions are defined.  `levels<-` is a little different because it is a primitive to (sub)assign the attributes of a factor, not the elements themselves.  There are plenty of examples of this type of function:

```
`<-`              # assignment
`[<-`             # sub-assignment
`[<-.data.frame`  # sub-assignment data.frame method
`dimnames<-`      # change dimname attribute
`attributes<-`    # change any attributes
```

Other binary operators can be called like that too:

```
`+`(1,2)  # 3
`-`(1,2)  # -1
`*`(1,2)  # 2
`/`(1,2)  # 0.5
```

Now that you know that, something like this should really blow your mind:

```
Data <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1)
names(Data)[1] <- "HI"              # How does that work?!? Magic! ;-)
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about when it makes sense to call functions that way, rather than the usual way?
I am working through @Marek's example in the linked question, but it would help to have a more explicit explanation.

Comment: @DrewSteen: for code clarity/readability reasons, I would say it never makes sense because `\`levels<-\`(foo,bar)` is the same as `levels(foo) <- bar`.  Using @Marek's example: `\`levels<-\`(as.factor(foo),bar)` is the same as `foo <- as.factor(foo); levels(foo) <- bar`.

Comment: Nice list. Don't you think `levels<-` is really just shorthand for `attr<-(x, "levels") <- value`, or at least it probably was until it was turned into a primitive and handed over to C-code.

Answer (score 31):

The reason for that "magic" is that the "assignment" form must have a real variable to work on. And the `factor(dat$product)` wasn't assigned to anything.

```
# This works since its done in several steps
x <- factor(dat$product)
levels(x) <- list(Tylenol=1:3, Advil=4:6, Bayer=7:9, Generic=10:12)
x

# This doesn't work although it's the "same" thing:
levels(factor(dat$product)) <- list(Tylenol=1:3, Advil=4:6, Bayer=7:9, Generic=10:12)
# Error: could not find function "factor<-"

# and this is the magic work-around that does work
`levels<-`(
  factor(dat$product),
  list(Tylenol=1:3, Advil=4:6, Bayer=7:9, Generic=10:12)
  )
```

Comment: +1 I think it would be cleaner to convert to factor first, then replace the levels via a `within()` and `transform()` call were the thusly modified object is returned and assigned.

Comment: @GavinSimpson - I agree, I only explain the magic, I don't defend it ;-)

Answer (score 17):

For user-code I do wonder why such language manipulations are used so? You ask what magic is this and others have pointed out that you are calling the replacement function that has the name `levels<-`. For most people this is magic and really the intended use is `levels(foo) <- bar`.

The use-case you show is different because `product` doesn't exist in the global environment so it only ever exists in the local environment of the call to `levels<-` thus the change you want to make does not persist - there was no reassignment of `dat`.

In these circumstances, `within()`  is the ideal function to use. You would naturally wish to write

```
levels(product) <- bar
```

in R but of course `product` doesn't exist as an object. `within()` gets around this because it sets up the environment you wish to run your R code against and evaluates your expression within that environment. Assigning the return object from the call to `within()` thus succeeds in the properly modified data frame.

Here is an example (you don't need to create new `datX` - I just do that so the intermediary steps remain at the end)

```
## one or t'other
#dat2 <- transform(dat, product = factor(product))
dat2 <- within(dat, product <- factor(product))

## then
dat3 <- within(dat2, 
               levels(product) <- list(Tylenol=1:3, Advil=4:6, 
                                       Bayer=7:9, Generic=10:12))
```

Which gives:

```
> head(dat3)
  product
1 Generic
2 Generic
3   Bayer
4   Bayer
5   Advil
6 Tylenol
> str(dat3)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ product: Factor w/ 4 levels "Tylenol","Advil",..: 4 4 3 3 2 1 4 2 3 4 ...
```

I struggle to see how constructs like the one you show are useful in the majority of cases - if you want to change the data, change the data, don't create another copy and change that (which is all the `levels<-` call is doing after all).