# Error in <my code> : target of assignment expands to non-language object

Tags: r, r-faq

I received the error

```
Error in <my code> : target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

or

```
Error in <my code> : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
```

or

```
Error in <my code> : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

What does it mean, and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 79):

These errors occur when you try to [assign a value](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/assignOps) to a variable that doesn't exist, or that R can't treat as a [`name`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/name).  (A *name* is a variable type that holds a variable name.)

To reproduce the errors, try:

```
1:2 <- 1
## Error in 1:2 <- 1 : target of assignment expands to non-language object

1 <- 1
## Error in 1 <- 1 : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment

mean() <- 1
## Error in mean() <- 1 : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

(Can you guess which of the three errors `NULL <- 1` returns?)

---

A little-known feature of R is that you can assign values to a string:

```
"x" <- 1 # same as x <- 1
```

This doesn't work if you try and construct the string using a more complex expression using, for example, [`paste`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/paste).

```
paste0("x", "y") <- 1
## Error: target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

See

[Create a variable name with "paste" in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5510966/134830) and
[How to name variables on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2679193/134830)

The solution to this is to use [`assign`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/assign):

```
assign(paste0("x", "y"), 1)
```

---

A common scenario in which this comes up is when trying to assign to columns of data frames. Often an attempt will be made to `paste()` together the left hand of the assignment, i.e.

```
paste0("my_dataframe$","my_column") <- my_value
```

Often the optimal solution here is *not* to resort to `get` or `assign` but to remember that we can refer to data frame columns by character variables using the `[` or `[[` operator:

```
x <- "my_column"
my_dataframe[,x] <- value #or...
my_dataframe[[x]] <- value
```

---

Similarly, you can't assign to the result of [`get`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/get).

```
get("x") <- 1
## Error in get("x") <- 1 : 
##   target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

The solution is either

```
assign("x", 1)
```

or simply

```
"x" <- 1
```

[Using get() with replacement functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14464442/134830) deals with a more complex case of `get` combined with a replacement function.

---

When using the `magrittr` package, accidental trailing [pipe operators](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/magrittr/topics/%25%26gt%3B%25) can cause this error too.

```
library(magrittr)
x <- 1 %>% 
y <- 2
##  Error in 1 %>% y <- 2 : 
##   target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

---

See also [Assignment in R language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10719836/134830) whose answers detail some of the arcana related to assignment, particularly the R language definition's description of [Subset Assignment](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment).