# Using Dplyr In A Function To Create New Dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

#### I'm Trying to create new dataframes from dplyr 0.4.3 functions using R 3.2.2.

What I want to do is create some new dataframes using dplyr::filter to separate out data from one ginormous dataframe into a bunch of smaller dataframes.

For my reproducible base case bog simple example, I used this:

```
filter(mtcars, cyl == 4)
```

I know I need to assign that to a dataframe of its own, so I started with:

```
paste("Cylinders:", x, sep = "") <- filter(mtcars, cyl == 4))
```

That didn't work -- it gave me the error found here: [Assignment Expands to Non-Language Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662162/error-in-my-code-target-of-assignment-expands-to-non-language-object)

From there, I found this: [Create A Variable Name with Paste in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510966/create-a-variable-name-with-paste-in-r)

*(also, big ups to the authors of the above)*

And that led me to this, which works:

```
assign(paste("gears_cars_cylinders", 4, sep = "_"), filter(mtcars, cyl == 4)) %>% 
    group_by(gear) %>% 
    summarise(number_of_cars = n())
```

and by "works," I mean I get a dataframe named gears_cars_cylinders_4 with all the goodies from

```
filter(mtcars, cyl == 4) %>% 
        group_by(gear) %>% 
        summarise(number_of_cars = n())
```

But ultimately, I think I need to wrap this whole thing in a function and be able to feed it the cylinder numbers from `mtcars$cyl`. I'm thinking something like `plyr::ldply(mtcars$cyl, function_name)`?

In my real-life data, I have about 70 different classes I need to split out into separate dataframes to drop into `DT::datatable` tabs in Shiny, which is a whole nuther mess. Anyway.

When I try this:

```
    function_name <- function(x){
    assign(paste("gears_cars_cylinders", x, sep = "_"), filter(mtcars, cyl == x)) %>% 
        group_by(gear) %>% 
        summarise(number_of_cars = n())
}
```

and then `function_name(6)`,

I get the output of the dataframe to the screen, but not a dataframe with the name.

Am I looking right over the answer here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign the new data frames into the environment from which you're calling `function_name()`. Try something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

foo <- function(x) {
  assign(paste("gears_cars_cylinders", x, sep = "_"),
         envir = parent.frame(),
         value = mtcars %>% 
           filter(cyl == x) %>% 
           count(gear))
}

for(cyl in sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))) foo(cyl)
ls()
#> [1] "cyl"                    "foo"                   
#> [3] "gears_cars_cylinders_4" "gears_cars_cylinders_6"
#> [5] "gears_cars_cylinders_8"
gears_cars_cylinders_4
#> Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#> 
#>    gear     n
#>   (dbl) (int)
#> 1     3     1
#> 2     4     8
#> 3     5     2
```

Comment: I can't help but feel this goes against everything I've been taught in R, in terms of grouping similar data in structures like `list`s. And if the point of `dplyr` is to simplify things, mashing it together with `assign` and environment manipulation seems like overkill. `gears <-  by(mtcars, mtcars$cyl, FUN=function(x) data.frame(table(x$gear)) )` and then accessing like `gears[["4"]]` seems so much less error-prone.

Comment: Yes that would normally be my thinking too. But maybe there are circumstances where you actually need these data frames as separate objects?

Comment: I honestly can't think of an occasion when that would be necessary. If you have the data.frames of `cyl4` `cyl6` `cyl18` floating about in the GlobalEnv then you need to loop over a `paste`d together vector of `"cyl"` and `i in c(4,6,18)` and use `get()`
to retrieve them, when you could just do `gears[[i]]`