# How to assign value directly to list object without intermediate variable?

Tags: r

```
y <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
y["b"] <- list(NULL)
```

works well.

Then I tried below scripts but failed:

```
> list(a = 1, b = 2)['b']<-list(NULL)
Error in list(a = 1, b = 2)["b"] <- list(NULL) : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I checked [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662162/error-in-my-code-target-of-assignment-expands-to-non-language-object),then tried `assign`:

```
> assign(list(a = 1, b = 2)['b'],list(NULL))
Error in assign(list(a = 1, b = 2)["b"], list(NULL)) : 
  invalid first argument
```

I think `list(a = 1, b = 2)['b']` equal to `y["b"]`,what's wrong with `list(a = 1, b = 2)['b']<-list(NULL)`?

Comment: It is the difference between `x <- 1` followed by `x <- 2` versus `1 <- 2`. What is the latter even supposed to mean?

Comment: @JohnColeman,then I will create a Intermediate variable just for assign value?

Comment: If it is going to be by assignment, you need a valid target. Perhaps there is some other way to mutate a list other than by assigning to a component.

Comment: What is the use-case of creating a list only to modify it even before you assign it to a variable? Why not just directly create the list that you want? This seems like a possible XY problem.

Comment: I just use this example for technical discussion.I think there's method to assign value directly without intermediate variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own function:

```
change <- function(my_list,name,value){
    my_list[name] <- value
    my_list
}
```

Then `change(list(a = 1, b = 2),'b',list(NULL))` works as (possibly) expected, although the semantics is that it creates a new list rather than modifies the old one. If you really wanted to modify an anonymous list in place, perhaps Rcpp could be used to do so with pointers.