# How can I access a data frame using string and modify the data frame?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, assign

I got a list of data frames, such as `c(df01,df02,df03)`.

Each data frame has three columns, `c("A", "B", "C")`.

I want to write a *for* loop to modify each column for each data frame. I tried:

```
for (df in c("df01", "df02", "df03")) {
   for (col in c("A", "B", "C")) {
      get(df)[[col]] <- 0
   }
}
```

I learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662162/error-in-my-code-target-of-assignment-expands-to-non-language-object) that we cannot assign value to the result of the get() function in R.

I also tried

```
assign(df[[col]], 0)
```

But this also does not work. The `assign()` function only assigns a value to a name, but here `df[[col]]` is not a name, but a column.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a "list of data.frames' or a "vector of names of data.frames"? Because it would be best to just have a list that you can iterator over so you don't have to bother with `get/assign` -- those aren't very R-like solutions. If you have a list, you can just `lapply` over it to transform it.

Comment: Referenced in Meta Stack Overflow question *[Duplicate of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400441/duplicate-of-stack-overflow)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the dataframes in a list and use `lapply` to change the columns

```
df_vec <- c("df01","df02","df03")
col_vec <- c("A","B","C")
result <- lapply(mget(df_vec), function(x) {x[col_vec] <- 0;x})
```

For these changes to reflect in original dataframe use `list2env` :

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Or `lapply(mget(df_vec), replace, col_vec, 0)` since the `col_vec` selects the columns by default.

Comment: @Ronak Thanks!! I got it to work, but I got a warning "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". Do you know possibly know the reason?

Comment: I'm also wondering what's the difference between df [ [colname] ] and df [colname];

Comment: Using double bracket you can select only one element and with single bracket you can select more than one. Here is a link explaining this in detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el