# Downloading file in CSV format through HTML form

Tags: r, rvest, httr

I am struggling with downloading csv data from the Alberta Electric System Operator site (AESO Site). The data are accessed by completing the form and then clicking the OK radio button.

Here's the code that I'm running.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)

get_metered_volumes_report <- function(start_date, end_date) {

  start_date <- as.Date(start_date)
  end_date <- as.Date(end_date)

  GET(
    url = "http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/ip/Market/Reports/PublicSummaryAllReportServlet",
    query = list(
      beginDate = format(start_date, "%m%d%Y"),
      endDate = format(end_date, "%m%d%Y"),
      contentType = "csv"
    )
  ) -> res

  content(res, as="text") %>% 
    stri_split_lines() %>% 
    flatten_chr() -> 

  read.csv(
    text = gsub("\"-\",", "",paste(c(paste(test[8:9], collapse=","), test[13:length(test)]), collapse="\n")),
    header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE
  )  %>% janitor::clean_names() %>% 
    tbl_df()

}

xdf <- get_metered_volumes_report("2019-12-12", "2021-01-13")
```

I'm facing an Error in read.csv(gsub(""-",", "", paste(c(paste(test[8:9], collapse = ","), : target of assignment expands to non-language object
Traceback:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662162/error-in-my-code-target-of-assignment-expands-to-non-language-object

Comment: It appears that you are trying to assign the results from content(...) to a function (read.csv).  Assign it to a variable.