# R S4 class, member function has no effect

Tags: r, function, member

I defined a member function for an S4 class (programming language R) which is supposed to add elements to a list, but it does nothing:

```
setClass("ListHolder",
representation(
    .list   = "list"
),
prototype(
    .list   = list()
))
setGeneric("add",
function(this,i) standardGeneric("add")
)
setMethod("add",
signature(this="ListHolder",i="numeric"),
definition = function(this,i){

    k <- length(this@.list)
    this@.list[[k+1]] <- i
})

testListHolder <- function(){

    lh <- new("ListHolder")  
    for(i in 1:10) add(lh,i)
    print(lh@.list)
}

testListHolder()
```

This will print an empty list. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**add** function is the problem : what you want to do is passing an object `ListHolder` into the function and modify it, which **R** does not support.

So, in your code above:

1. **setMethod:** **add(Object, i)**, add `return(this)` statement at the end of function **add**.
2. **testListHolder:** replace `lh` after **add**, `for(i in 1:10) lh <- add(lh,i)`

**EDIT:** also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497947/call-by-reference-in-r-using-function-to-modify-an-object)(use function to modify an object) question