# R can't find a function

Tags: r

I'm trying to rename a column without creating an object (dataframe).

When I run:

```
names(data.frame(cbind(LETTERS[1:3],1:3)))[1]<-"A"
```

I get:

```
Error in names(data.frame(cbind(LETTERS[1:3], 1:3)))[1] <- "A" : could not find function "data.frame<-"
```

If I run:

```
X<-data.frame(cbind(LETTERS[1:3],1:3))
colnames(X)[1]<-"letters"
X
```

I'll see the column name changed because I made a data frame and then changed it. I'm pretty sure these two code snippets are the same except for the object creation. I don't know if R is just inflexible on this function and I have to create objects sometimes and not others. But the error "...could not find function" seemed a bit odd to me. Can someone explain this error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have said, you need to name the data frame first. (Though there is a way to avoid that; stay tuned.) But you knew that already, and wanted to know why.  Here it is.

Functions like this are replacement functions. They're a kind of "syntactic sugar" that makes certain kind of operations simpler.  See this answer for details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11563358/210673.

Here's an example of a replacement function and what it's really equal to.

```
names(d) <- c("A","B")
d <- `names<-`(d, c("A","B"))
```

Therefore your call is really (taking the result from `cbind` out for simplicity)

```
tmp <- cbind(LETTERS[1:3],1:3)
data.frame(tmp) <- `names<-`(data.frame(tmp), c("A","B"))
```

which in turn is trying to call

```
tmp <- `data.frame<-`(tmp, `names<-`(data.frame(tmp), c("A","B")))
```

and it fails because there is no `data.frame<-` function.

You can accomplish what you want by not using the syntactic sugar version of `names<-` but instead using it directly, as this won't try to do the assignment.

```
`names<-`(data.frame(tmp), c("A","B"))
```

Comment: +1.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449366/levels-what-sorcery-is-this

Answer (score 5):

What do you expect the return value of your first command to be?  Consider:

```
> (colnames(X)[1]<-"letters")
[1] "letters"
```

So even there in order to see the data frame output you have to run another command.  Maybe `setNames` gets you part of the way to where you want to be:

```
> setNames(data.frame(cbind(LETTERS[1:3],1:3)), c("letters"))
  letters NA
1       A  1
2       B  2
3       C  3
```

Or better yet:

```
> data.frame(letters=LETTERS[1:3], 1:3)
  letters V2
1       A  1
2       B  2
3       C  3
```