# Concerning R, when defining a Replacement Function, do the arguments have to be named as/like "x" and "value"?

Tags: r, function

By "replacement functions" I mean those mentioned in this thread [What are Replacement Functions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563154/what-are-replacement-functions-in-r), ones that look like `'length<-'(x, value)`. When I was working with such functions I encountered something weird. It seems that a replacement function only works when variables are named according to a certain rule.

Here is my code:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
```

I will try to change the first element of `a`, using one of the 3 replacement functions below.

```
'first0<-' <- function(x, value){
  x[1] <- value
  x
}

first0(a) <- 5
a
# returns [1] 5 2 3.
```

The first one works pretty well... but then when I change the name of arguments in the definition,

```
'first1<-' <- function(somex, somevalue){
  somex[1] <- somevalue
  somex
}

first1(a) <- 9
# Error in `first1<-`(`*tmp*`, value = 9) : unused argument (value = 9)
a
# returns [1] 5 2 3
```

It fails to work, though the following code is OK:

```
a <- 'first1<-'(a, 9)
a
# returns [1] 9 2 3
```

Some other names work well, too, if they are similar to `x` and `value`, it seems:

```
'first2<-' <- function(x11, value11){
  x11[1] <- value11
  x11
}

first2(a) <- 33
a
# returns [1] 33  2  3
```

This doesn't make sense to me. Do the names of variables actually matter or did I make some mistakes?

Comment: I think it may have been passed back to `first0`, though I'm not sure.  Good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things going on here. First, the only real rule of replacement functions is that the new value will be passed as a parameter named `value` and it will be the last parameter. That's why when you specify the signature `function(somex, somevalue)`, you get the error `unused argument (value = 9)` and the assignment doesn't work.

Secondly, things work with the signature `function(x11, value11)` thanks to partial matching of parameter names in R. Consider this example

```
f<-function(a, value1234=5) {
    print(value1234)
}    
f(value=5)
# [1] 5
```

Note that `5` is returned.  This behavior is defined under [argument matching](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Argument-matching) in the language definition.

Another way to see what's going on is to print the call signature of what's actually being called.

```
'first0<-' <- function(x, value){
    print(sys.call())
    x[1] <- value
    x
}
a <- c(1,2,3)
first0(a) <- 5
# `first0<-`(`*tmp*`, value = 5)
```

So the first parameter is actually passed as an unnamed positional parameter, and the new value is passed as the named parameter `value=`. This is the only parameter name that matters.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! So one of the parameters does have a fixed name (I still feel this is strange!). How about `a <- 'first1<-'(a, 9)`? Isn't it the same thing as `first1(a) <- 9`? Why does the former work even when I use `first1 <- function(somex, somevalue)` while the latter does not?

Comment: When you call `a <- 'first1<-'(a, 9)`, that's resolved using positional parameters. Nothing is named. But when R turns `first1(a) <- 9` into a function call, it turns it into `a <- 'first1<-'(a, value=9)`. When you use a parameter name, you are no longer using positional parameters.