# Function name in single quotation marks in R

Tags: r, function

It may be a silly question but I have been bothered for quite a while. I've seen people use single quotation marks to surround the function name when they are defining a function. I keep wondering the benefit of doing so. Below is a naive example

```
'row.mean' <- function(mat){
    return(apply(mat, 1, mean))
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure they weren't backticks?

Comment: Forgive my sloppy observation. You are right! they were backticks.

Comment: They are also necessary to write assignment functions, e.g. `row.mean<-`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going off Richard's assumption, the back ticks allows you to use symbols in names which are normally not allowed. See:

```
`add+5` <- function(x) {return(x+5)}
```

defines a function, but

```
add+5 <-  function(x) {return(x+5)}
```

returns

```
Error in add + 5 <- function(x) { : object 'add' not found
```

To refer to the function, you need to explicitly use the back ticks as well.

```
> `add+5`(3)
[1] 8
```

To see the code for this function, simply call it without its arguments:

```
> `add+5`
function(x) {return(x+5)}
```

See also this comment which deals with the difference between the backtick and quotes in name assignment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-December/121608.html

Note, the usage of back ticks is much more general. For example, in a data frame you can have columns named with integers (maybe from using `reshape::cast` on integer factors).

For example:

```
test = data.frame(a = "a", b = "b")
names(test) <- c(1,2)
```

and to retrieve these columns you can use the backtick in conjunction with the `$` operator, e.g.:

```
> test$1
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "test$1"
```

but

```
> test$`1`
[1] a
Levels: a
```

Funnily you can't use back ticks in assigning the data frame column names; the following doesn't work:

```
test = data.frame(`1` = "a", `2` = "b")
```

And responding to statechular's comments, here are the two more use cases.

**In fix functions**

Using the `%` symbol we can naively define the dot product between vectors `x` and `y`:

```
`%.%` <- function(x,y){

    sum(x * y)

}
```

which gives

```
> c(1,2) %.% c(1,2)
[1] 5
```

for more, see: http://dennisphdblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/16/infix-functions-in-r/

**Replacement functions**

Here is a great answer demonstrating what these are: [What are Replacement Functions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563154/what-are-replacement-functions-in-r)

Comment: Thank Alex! That makes sense. Also found two other advantages of using backticks: (1) allows user-defined infix functions; and (2) replacement functions

Comment: thanks, I've updated by answer to include these cases.

Comment: What's even more interesting about the names is you can't assign numbers with backticks, but R can... `split(1, 1)` But you can access them with backticks with split(1,1)$`1`

Comment: interesting indeed! unfortunately we don't find much help in querying the underlying code of `split`. However, querying `reshape::cast` gives this bit: ` if (any(names(data) == value)) 
        names(data)[names(data) == value] <- "value"`