# R chain operator usage

Tags: r, function

I understood that in `R` we can create special function by using chain operator, but how can I know the function implementation/code for the chain operator?

If I want to find out source for a function, I use `> functionname`

But when I tried to find source code for operator `> "%*%"`  it didn't print anything. Could someone please help me how I can find out source code for above chain operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the pipe operator, you need to have the package `magrittr` loaded or `dplyr` loaded using `library`. Then you need to use backticks to access the function definition:

```
library(dplyr)
`%>%`
```

which gives

```
function (lhs, rhs)     {
    lhs <- substitute(lhs)
    rhs <- substitute(rhs)
    if (is.call(rhs) && identical(rhs[[1]], quote(`(`))) 
        rhs <- eval(rhs, parent.frame(), parent.frame())
    ...
```

The reason for this is explained here [Function name in single quotation marks in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902925/function-name-in-single-quotation-marks-in-r/25902979#25902979)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! No, I am talking about * operator. How can I find source for %*%

Comment: @Nambari You can use: ` `%*%` ` which returns: ``unction (x, y)  .Primitive("%*%")`

Comment: Ok, When I used back tick, it gave me .Primitive("%*%"), now I need to figure out how can I find out source for these primitive functions. Thanks!

Comment: @RStudent: thanks! it seems we both posted comment almost same time.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, it is do_matprod function call.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function) can give a few hints. Here is a search in R source looking for [do_matprod](https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=do_matprod&type=Code). You seem to be rigth.