# R's dim() function: by value or by reference

Tags: r

I am a new learner of R. I use Python, C and Fortran, so it is a little bit hard for me to understand what R does.

`dim(data)` returns the data's dim attribute. This is a function that returns a value. How can one assign a value to another value by something like `dim(data) <- c(2, 2)`?

And also, R passes everything by value, right? `dim(data)` does not return the address of `dim` attribute. This is making it more confusing, that we can use `dim(data) <- c(2, 2)` to assign a new dimension.

Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563154/what-are-replacement-functions-in-r

Comment: @BenBolker Great! Thank you so much. So it is a special case where the variable is passed by reference inside?

Comment: more or less, although there may still be some copying involved ...