# Find all words that have "<-" at the end of the word OR in front of a dot

Tags: regex, r

How do I pull out all words that have the symbol "`<-`" either at the end of the word or somewhere in between but in the latter case only if the "`<-`" symbol is followed by a dot.

To put it into context. Exercise 6.5.3 a. of *Hadley Wickhams - Advanced R*  asks the reader to list all replacement functions in the base package.

Replacement function that only have one method are indicated by the symbol `<-` 
right at the end of the function name. Generic functions, however, have their
method name attached to the name of the replacement form (with a dot), such that the `<-` is no longer at the end of the function name. Example `split<-.data.frame`

EDIT:

```
obj <- mget(ls("package:base"), inherits = TRUE)
funs <- Filter(is.function, objs)
```

This is how you pull out all functions in the base package. Now I want to find only the replacement functions.

Comment: Regex for that is `\b\w+<-(?![\w.])|\b\w+<-\.\w+\b`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want all base package replacement functions and their respective S3 methods, you can try

```
ls(envir = as.environment("package:base"), pattern = "<-")
```

With no packages loaded, this gives the following result:

> ```
>  [1] "<<-"                     "<-"                      "[<-"                    
>  [4] "[[<-"                    "@<-"                     "$<-"                    
>  [7] "attr<-"                  "attributes<-"            "body<-"                 
> [10] "class<-"                 "colnames<-"              "comment<-"              
> [13] "[<-.data.frame"          "[[<-.data.frame"         "$<-.data.frame"         
> [16] "[<-.Date"                "diag<-"                  "dim<-"                  
> [19] "dimnames<-"              "dimnames<-.data.frame"   "Encoding<-"             
> [22] "environment<-"           "[<-.factor"              "[[<-.factor"            
> [25] "formals<-"               "is.na<-"                 "is.na<-.default"        
> [28] "is.na<-.factor"          "is.na<-.numeric_version" "length<-"               
> [31] "length<-.factor"         "levels<-"                "levels<-.factor"        
> [34] "mode<-"                  "mostattributes<-"        "names<-"                
> [37] "names<-.POSIXlt"         "[<-.numeric_version"     "[[<-.numeric_version"   
> [40] "oldClass<-"              "parent.env<-"            "[<-.POSIXct"            
> [43] "[<-.POSIXlt"             "regmatches<-"            "row.names<-"            
> [46] "rownames<-"              "row.names<-.data.frame"  "row.names<-.default"    
> [49] "split<-"                 "split<-.data.frame"      "split<-.default"        
> [52] "storage.mode<-"          "substr<-"                "substring<-"            
> [55] "units<-"                 "units<-.difftime"
> ```

Thanks to @42 for helping me improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(v1, "\\w+<-$|\\w*<-\\.\\S+")
#[1] "split<-.data.frame" NA                   "splitdata<-"
```

#### data

```
v1 <-  c("split<-.data.frame", "split<-data", "splitdata<-")
```