# Append function that assign new value

Tags: arrays, r

I am trying to create a function `Append` that does not return a value but directly extend the first variable. Currently, to append `y` to `x` I do

```
x = append(x,y)
```

I would like to be able to do

```
Append(x,y)
```

and get the same result. I first thought of something like

```
Append = function(a,b,VarName) assign(VarName,append(a,b), envir = .GlobalEnv)
Append(x,y,"x")
```

It works but it is quite unsatisfying to have to pass the name of the original variable. Is there a better solution?

Comment: For those wondering, I have no practical application in mind when asking this question. I am just trying to learn.

Comment: assign (deparse (substitute  (...)), ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're doing this to learn, maybe a more R-like approach to in-place modification is a replacement function

```
`append_to<-` = function(x, ..., value)
    append(x, ..., values=value)
```

used as

```
x = 1:5
append_to(x) <- 5:1
y = 1:5
append_to(y, after=3) <- c(3:1, 1:3)
```

resulting in

```
> x
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1
> y
 [1] 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Awesome +1! Is there any reason why you used `...` as argument of `append_to<-`?

Comment: Is there a term for this kind of function definition?

Comment: @Remi.b ; [replacement functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563154/what-are-replacement-functions-in-r)

Comment: @Remi.b I updated my answer to indicate the use of additional arguments in the replacement function.

Answer (score 1):

This is very un-R but:

```
Append <- function(x, y) {
  assign(deparse(substitute(x)),append(x,y), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

So you can do things like:

```
x <- 1:5

y <- 6

Append(x, y)

x # has a 6 at the end
```

edit: Another Carl pointed this out in the comments