# How does colnames function assign new column names?

Tags: r, function, variable-assignment

I've used this function so many times but only now thought 'why does it work?'.
How can R's colnames() function assign new column names to a data frame?
I mean I get how colnames(df) will return the column names of a data frame. But how can it also assign new ones?

```
aa <- mtcars
colnames(aa)
colnames(aa) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(aa)]
colnames(aa)
# ^ how can colnames function either return column names or assign new ones? It's just a function.

# but we can't change the number of columns this way:
ncol(aa)
ncol(aa) <- 10
```

As at now the colnames function is:

```
function (x, do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = "col") 
{
    if (is.data.frame(x) && do.NULL) 
        return(names(x))
    dn <- dimnames(x)
    if (!is.null(dn[[2L]])) 
        dn[[2L]]
    else {
        nc <- NCOL(x)
        if (do.NULL) 
            NULL
        else if (nc > 0L) 
            paste0(prefix, seq_len(nc))
        else character()
    }
}
<bytecode: 0x00000000091f1710>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

***Q:*** *I can't see how this is assigning new column names to data frame.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449366/levels-what-sorcery-is-this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`colnames` on the left hand side of a `<-` is not the same function as on the right hand side.  The former is called a replacement function and its name is `colnames<-`.

### Displaying source

You can see its code by typing this at the R console:

```
`colnames<-`
```

The source displayed by that looks like this:

```
`colnames<-` <- function(x, value) { ...modify x...; x }
```

where the first argument `x` refers to the argument on the left hand side and the second argument`, value`, is the right hand side of the `<-`.  They are both input to the replacement function and then R assigns the result of running the replacement function back to `x`.

### Simple example of replacement function

For example, here is a simple replacement function:

```
# define simple replacement function
`add_n<-` <- function(x, value) x + value  

# test
my_number <- 4
add_n(my_number) <- 3
my_number
## [1] 7
```

### More info

There is some discussion of replacement functions here: [What are Replacement Functions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563154/what-are-replacement-functions-in-r)