# R: can I update the class of a an object in a magrittr pipe?

Tags: r, purrr, magrittr

I have a piece of code where I update the class of the object. But I have to break the follow of the code to assign the class. Is there an elegant to to assign the class but continue the pipe so I have one pipe all the way to the final result? I suspect there might be something in {purrr}?

```r
library(disk.frame)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquery)

a = nycflights13::airports %>%
  as.disk.frame

class(a) <- c(class(a), "data.frame")

a %>% 
  query("SELECT name, lat, lon ORDER BY lat DESC LIMIT 5")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can just use `"class<-"()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

x <- 1:10 %>%
    "class<-"("foo")
x
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "foo"
```

#### Details

Generally, in R, when you can assign to a function's output, e.g. `class(x) <- "foo"`, what you're using is a "replacement function", e.g. `"class<-"()`. A good discussion of this on Stack Overflow can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563154/what-are-replacement-functions-in-r).

Comment: magrittr has the alias set_class

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Good point; I didn't realize that since I have the CRAN version of `magrittr`. I'll add something later about being able to do that with the dev version of it

Comment: oh it's more my mistake then, I thought it was available in cran version

Answer (score 2):

Using `setattr()` from package `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
x <- 1:10
x %>% setattr("class", c(class(x), "xiaodai's special"))
x

 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
attr(,"class")
[1] "integer"           "xiaodai's special"
```