# R - Function Equals Function

Tags: r

My question is fairly difficult to search for, as I just come across APIs for the "equals" function instead!

If I have the following line, working upon the matrix `Gl`:

```
diag(Gl)=diag(Gl)+1
```

Is this equivalent to modifying `Gl` itself?

Comment: Correct - you are modifying the diagonal of ``Gl``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is modifying the diagonal of `Gl` *in place*. This is an example of a moderately obscure R language feature called a [*replacement function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563154/what-are-replacement-functions-in-r). From  the [R language manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) (section 3.4.4, about the equivalent operation for `names`):

> The same mechanism can be applied to functions other than `[`. The replacement function has the same name with `<-` pasted on. Its last argument, which must be called `value`, is the new value to be assigned. For example,

> > `names(x) <- c("a","b")`

> is equivalent to

```r
   `*tmp*` <- x
   x <- "names<-"(`*tmp*`, value=c("a","b"))
   rm(`*tmp*`)
```

(sorry about formatting). You can print the `` `diag<-` `` function to see (surround the name in back-ticks `` ` ` ``) so the parser doesn't get confused, or `getAnywhere("diag<-")`)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's assigning.  Simple example:

```
 > g1 <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
 > g1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
 > diag(g1) = diag(g1) + 1
 > g1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    2    5
```

When you type "dia", then **RStudio** autofills with the options of `diag()` and `diag<-`, with some info on the replacement part.