# Is there literature on how to set up own square bracket functions in R?

Tags: r, function, generic-programming

I'm struggling writing functions for my own class. [Hadley Wickham suggests](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) to implement functions for square bracket functions like `[`, `[<-` etc. But how is this done?
After the comment from r.user.05apr, I manage to write

```
`[.test`  <- function(x, y){
  substr(x, start = y[1], stop = y[length(y)])
} 
foo <- "hello world"
class(foo) <- "test"
foo[2:5] #what correctly returns "ello"
```

I did find [sites on how they are called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260951/using-square-bracket-as-a-function-for-lapply-in-r), but no explanations and examples on how they are defined. For example for the mentioned `[<-` function I guess, three arguments are needed, the object to manipulate, the index showing which elements of the objects shall be replaced and finally a replacement. I managed to get the result wanted by

```
`[<-.test` <- function(obj, index, value){
  tmp <- unlist(strsplit(obj, ""))
  tmp[index] <- value
  return(paste(tmp, collapse = ""))
} 

foo <- "hello world"
class(foo) <- "test"
foo[c(2, 5)] <- "X"
```

but only after figuring out that the third element has to be called `value` and nothing else. So I'm looking for a good, easy to understand (this criteria is not met by [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html); more like [Creating R Packages by Friedrich Leisch](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf)) piece of literature covering the methods mentioned by Wickham.

Comment: `\`[.test`\` maybe?

Comment: Thank you this help for the first problem, but I realized my problem is broader: I'm looking for some kind of literature to learn how these functions are build correctly. I changed the question therefore.