# lapply function arguments in R

Tags: python, r, github

I have been converting an R script into python script and I stumbled upon this strange way of calling lapply() function in R. It's a github project (SnoLyze) that I am converting into python.

```
lapply(conjunctionAttributeSet, "[", , "sctid")
```

Let's suppose the first argument is a list with values, named conjunctionAttributeSet. What about these others? Shouldn't this function take two arguments, X and FUN? This code is working fine too! How? What am I missing?

Comment: That is a shorthand of `lapply(conjunctionAttributeSet, function(x) x[, "sctid"])`

Comment: Argument `X` is `conjunctionAttributeSet`, the function `FUN` is `"["` and then you have further arguments that the function needs and that are passed to it.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260951/using-square-bracket-as-a-function-for-lapply-in-r

Comment: @DarrenTsai If the *two*  commas after `"["` are right, then `x` should be bideimensional:  `x[, "sctid"]`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes I miss it! Thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function being applied is `[`, with extra blank argument `,` and an extra argument `"sctid"`. This is saying "extract the "sctid" column from each element of `conjunctionAttributeSet`.

The code `results = lapply(conjunctionAttributeSet, "[", , "sctid")` is equivalent to

```
results = list()

for(i in seq_along(conjunctionAttributeSet)) {
  results[[i]] = conjunctionAttributeSet[[i]][, "sctid"]
}
```

Comment: With two commas isn't it `conjunctionAttributeSet[[i]][, "sctid"]`?

Comment: Thanks, missed the comma!