# How to create an assignment method for an S3 object?

Tags: r

I have an S3 object in R, something like:

```
myObject <- list(
    someParameter1 = 4,
    someList = 1:10
)
class(myObject) <- "myClass"
```

I created an extraction method for this class:

```
"[.myClass" <- function(x, i) {
    x$someList[i] * x$someParameter1
}
myObject[5]
# 20
```

Now I want to create an assignment method (from `?Extract` I understand that's called a subassignment), so that I can write:

```
myObject[5] <- 250
myObject[5]
# 1000
```

I first naively tried to write this as

```
"[<-.myClass" <- function(x, i, value) {
    x$someList[i] <- value
}
```

but for some reason this replaces `myObject` with `value`. I suspect I must modify `x` and then `assign("someName", x, pos=somewhere)`, but how can I reliably determine `someName` and `somewhere`?

Or is there an different way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return `x`:

```
"[<-.myClass" <- function(x, i, value) {
    x$someList[i] <- value
    x
}
```

If you don't use `return` in your function call, the value of the last evaluated expression will be returned.  In the case of your original function, the value of the expression is `value`.  To illustrate:

```
"[<-.myClass" <- function(x, i, value) {
    print(x$someList[i] <- value)
    x
}
myObject[5] <- 250
# [1] 250
```

Comment: correct, would you mind explaining why I need to return x because I don't get it...

Comment: That's what I saw as well, but why does this assignment replace the whole object? Is the assignment somehow propagated downwards or something like this?

Comment: @Calimo: because `<-` is recursive. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10491881/271616).

Comment: Ok, so `myObject[5] <- 250` is in fact `myObject <- \`[<-.myClass\`(myObject, 5, 250)`. Now it's obvious, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To complement Joshua Ulrich's excellent answer, the reason you need to return `x` is because R translates

```
myObject[5] <- 250
```

into

```
myObject <- `[<-.myClass`(myObject, 5, 250)
```

It is immediately clear why you need to return `x` (which was `myObject` outside the function): the return value is assigned to myObject.