# Understanding code for custom in-place modification function?

Tags: r, data.table

I came across this post: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/speeding-up-perception-tp3640920p3646694.html from Matt Dowle, discussing some early? implementation ideas of the `data.table` package.

He uses the following code:

```
x = list(a = 1:10000, b = 1:10000) 
class(x) = "newclass" 
"[<-.newclass" = function(x,i,j,value) x      # i.e. do nothing 
tracemem(x)
x[1, 2] = 42L
```

**Specifically I am looking at:**

```
"[<-.newclass" = function(x,i,j,value) x
```

I am trying to understand what is done there and how i could use this notation.

It looks to me like:

- i is the row index
- j is column index
- value is the value to be assigned
- x is the object under consideration

My best guess would therefore be that i define a custom function for in place modification (for a given class).

`[<-.newclass`  is in class modification for class newclass.

Understanding what happens:
Usually the following code should return an error:

```
x = list(a = 1:10000, b = 1:10000) 
x[1, 2] = 42L
```

so i guess the sample code does not have any practical use.

**Attempt to use the logic:**

A simple non-sense try would be to square the value to be inserted:

```
x[i, j] <- value^2
```

Full try:

```
> x = matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
> class(x) = "newclass"
> "[<-.newclass" = function(x, i, j, value) x[i, j] <- value^2 # i.e. do something
> x[1, 2] = 9
Error: C stack usage  19923536 is too close to the limit
```

This doesnt seem to work.

**My question(s):**

```
"[<-.newclass" = function(x,i,j,value) x
```

How exactly does this notation work and how would I use it?

(I add data.table tag since the linked discussion is about the "by-reference" in place modification in data.table, i think).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `` `[<-`() `` function is (traditionally) used for [subassignment](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment), and is, more broadly, a type of [replacement function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563154/what-are-replacement-functions-in-r). It is also generic (more specifically, an [internal generic](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/InternalMethods.html)), which allows you to [write custom methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711110/how-to-create-an-assignment-method-for-an-s3-object) for it, as you correctly surmised.

### Replacement functions

In general, when you call a replacement function, such as ...

```r
foo(x) <- bar(y)
```

... the expression on the right hand side of `<-` (so here `bar(y)`) gets passed as a named `value` argument to `` `foo<-`() `` with `x` as the first argument, and the object `x` is reassigned with the result: that is, the said call is equivalent to writing:

```r
x <- `foo<-`(x, value = bar(y))
```

So in order to work at all, all replacement functions must take at least two arguments, one of which must be named `value`.
Most replacement functions only have these two arguments, but there are also exceptions: such as [`` `attr<-` ``](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/attr.html) and, typically, *subassignment*.

#### Subassignment

When you have a subassignment call like `x[i, j] <- y`, `i` and `j` get passed as additional arguments to the `` `[<-`() `` function with `x` and `y` as the first and `value` arguments, respectively:

```r
x <- `[<-`(x, i, j, value = y) # x[i, j] <- y
```

In the case of a `matrix` or a `data.frame`, `i` and `j` would be used for selecting rows and columns; but in general, this does not need to be the case. A method for a custom class could do anything with the arguments. Consider this example:

```r
x <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
class(x) <- "newclass" 

`[<-.newclass` <- function(x, y, z, value) {
  x + (y - z) * value # absolute nonsense
}

x[1, 2] <- 9
x
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   -8   -5   -2
#> [2,]   -7   -4   -1
#> [3,]   -6   -3    0
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "newclass"
```

Is this useful or reasonable? *Probably not.* But is it valid R code? *Absolutely!*

It's less common to see custom subassignment methods in real applications, as `` `[<-`() `` usually "just works" as you might expect it to, based on the underlying object of your class. A notable exception is [`` `[<-.data.frame` ``](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html), where the underlying object is a list, but subassignment behaves matrix-like. (On the other hand, many classes *do* need a custom sub*setting* method, as the default `` `[`() `` method drops most attributes, including the `class` attribute, see `` ?`[` `` for details).

---

**As to why your example doesn't work:** remember that you are writing a method for a generic function, and all the regular rules apply. If we use the functional form of `` `[<-`() `` and expand the method dispatch in your example, we can see immediately why it fails:

```r
`[<-.newclass` <- function(x, i, j, value) {
  x <- `[<-.newclass`(x, i, j, value = value^2)  # x[i, j] <- value^2
}
```

That is, the function was defined recursively, without a base case, resulting in an infinite loop. One way to get around this would be to `unclass(x)` before calling the next method:

```r
`[<-.newclass` <- function(x, i, j, value) {
  x <- unclass(x)
  x[i, j] <- value^2
  x # typically you would also add the class back here
}
```

(Or, using a somewhat more advanced technique, the body could also be replaced with an explicit next method like this: `NextMethod(value = value^2)`. This plays nicer with inheritance and superclasses.)

And just to verify that it works:

```r
x <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
class(x) <- "newclass" 

x[1, 2] <- 9
x
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1   81    7
#> [2,]    2    5    8
#> [3,]    3    6    9
```

Perfectly confusing!

---

As for the context of Dowle's "do nothing" subassignment example, I believe this was to illustrate that back in R 2.13.0, a custom subassignment method would always cause a deep copy of the object to be made, even if the method itself did nothing at all. (This is no longer the case, since R 3.1.0 I believe.)

Created on 2018-08-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).