# Set column names while calling a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply, combn

Consider we have a numeric data.frame `foo` and want to find the sum of each two columns:

```
foo <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=4:8,z=10:14, w=8:4)
bar <- combn(colnames(foo), 2, function(x) foo[,x[1]] + foo[,x[2]])
bar
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    5   11    9   14   12   18
#[2,]    7   13    9   16   12   18
#[3,]    9   15    9   18   12   18
#[4,]   11   17    9   20   12   18
#[5,]   13   19    9   22   12   18
```

Everything is fine, except the column names that are missing from `bar`. I want column names of `bar` to show the related columns in `foo`, for instance in this example:

```
colnames(bar) <- apply(combn(colnames(foo),2), 2, paste0,collapse="")
colnames(bar)
#[1] "xy" "xz" "xw" "yz" "yw" "zw"
```

This is simple, but I want to perform column labeling in the same `bar <- combn(...)` command. Is there anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but it obfuscates your code. The tradeoff between brevity and clarity here is acute.

To understand how it works, I reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449366/levels-what-sorcery-is-this).

```
colnames(x) <- y
```

Is internally rewritten as

```
x <- `colnames<-`(x,y)
```

You can then do the translation yourself.

```
bar <- `colnames<-`(combn(colnames(foo), 2, function(x) foo[,x[1]] + foo[,x[2]]),
                    apply(combn(colnames(foo),2), 2, paste0,collapse=""))
```

In many cases, however, it's not worth the mental and syntactic gymnastics required to collapse lines of code in this way. Multiple lines tend to be clearer to follow.

Comment: +1 for using multiple lines. Clarity before brevity, code is for you to read, not computers.

Comment: Interesting answer. Is there anyway to assign column name to `function(x)` result? If so, we might skip the `apply(...)` function. I know it does not work inside `combn()` function according to @RomanLuštrik answer, but it might be useful elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You start with a data.frame, not a matrix. Not that important, but it helps to keep up with the jargon we usually use.

What you're after is not possible. If you look at the code of `combn`, when the result is simplified, it uses no dimension names.

```
    }
    if (simplify) 
        array(out, dim.use)
    else out
}
```

You can either hack the function and make it add dimension names, or, you can add it manually to your result *post festum*.

Comment: Thanks, I changed matrix to data.frame in the OP