# Applying names to dataframe column variables

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 563 columns in which I would like to change the names of column variables in all except the first 2 columns using a character vector(Cnames) of length 561. I tried using:

```
colnames(df[,3:563]) <- Cnames
```

But nothing happens here. But if I try changing the names of all column variables as follows then renaming works:

```
CoName <- c("char0", "char01", Cnames)
colnames(df) <- CoName
```

Can someone tell me why this happens? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried that but get an error:                                    Error in colnames(df)[, 3:563] <- Cnames : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Comment: look at the code again, you have one `,` too much.

Comment: Or just `colnames(df)[-seq_len(2)] <- Cnames`

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
colnames(df)[3:563] <- Cnames
```

which will work.

I'm not familiar with the R memory model, but I suspect that the call to `colnames(df[,3:563])` returns a new, temporary object which has nothing to do with the original data frame. On the other hand, `colnames(df)` will allow you to directly update the reference in the data frame.

Comment: or make it general `colnames(df)[3:ncol(df)] <- Cnames`

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427925/difference-between-namesdf1-and-namesdf1) on why this is happening