# How to name list elements

Tags: r

I create a list and I want to name the elements of the list. Could somebody help me on this?

```
LL <- vector(mode = "list")

L11 <- seq(1, 10)
L12 <- seq(11, 20)
LL[[length(LL)+1]] <- cbind(L11, L12)   
# I want to name LL[[1]] as "L1", but this does not work
names(LL[[length(LL)]]) <- c("L1")

L21 <- seq(21, 30)
L22 <- seq(31, 40)
LL[[length(LL)+1]] <- cbind(L21, L22)
# I want to name LL[[2]] as "L2", but this does not work
names(LL[[length(LL)]]) <- c("L2")

LL
```

Comment: Are you trying to do `names(LL) <- c("L1", "L2")`?

Comment: Was just going to offer that... Probably a more general solution is `names(LL) <- paste0("L", 1:length(LL))`

Comment: yes, indeed, but I want to name each element separately. More generally how do we name an element of a list.

Comment: Then just `names(LL)[1L] <- "L1"` and etc. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427925/difference-between-namesdf1-and-namesdf1) in order to understand the difference.

Comment: This is it. Thank you a lot David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg) (see comment above):

```
names(LL)[1L] <- "L1"
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427925/difference-between-namesdf1-and-namesdf1) to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
LL <- vector(mode = "list") 
LL$l1 <- seq(1, 10)
LL$l2 <- seq(11, 20)
```