# How to add a prefix to a subset of variables

Tags: r, subset, renaming

I learned via this post ([Adding a prefix to column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872081/adding-a-prefix-to-column-names)) how to change the names of all the variables in a dataset at once, but I can't seem to change the name of only a subset of those variables. The dataset has 358 variables in total, and I am able to add a prefix to all of the variables, but not just a subset.

I am using the following code, but the names don't seem to be changing.

```
colnames(y6t1data[,75:358]) <- paste("Y6T1",colnames(y6t1data[,75:358]), sep = "_")
```

Comment: You need `colnames(y6t1data)[75:358] <- ` and similarly on the RHS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \`names(df\[1\]) <- \` and \`names(df)\[1\] <- \`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427925/difference-between-namesdf1-and-namesdf1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `data.table` framework, an intuitive way to do that is:

```
setnames(y6t1data, 75:358, paste("Y6T1",names(y6t1data)[75:358], sep = "_")
```

This syntax alows you to transform names, by regex...

For more info, pleace check:

```
? setnames
```