# Removing first character from multiple column names

Tags: r, dataframe, substring, rename

My question is about renaming multiple column names at once.

I have a dataframe called 'growth' with 46 columns.

Columns 2:46 are all named as dates, but all of the dates have an X in front of them, e.g. 'X1981'.

Naturally I want to remove the X from all of the column names.

I cannot understand why the following is not working:

```
colnames(growth[ ,2:length(growth)]) <- substring(colnames(growth[ ,2:length(growth)]),2)
```

Please help me with some insights.

Comment: Probably related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427925/difference-between-namesdf1-and-namesdf1)

Comment: You actually should reshape your wide data to long format, having a *Year* column and values in adjacent column. This scales better and computation is much easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \`names(df\[1\]) <- \` and \`names(df)\[1\] <- \`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427925/difference-between-namesdf1-and-namesdf1)

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I changed the instruction to...

```
names(growth)[2:46] <- substring(names(growth)[2:46],2)
```

...and now it works. Clearly it had something to do with how I was subsetting the columns.

Comment: Good job. Note that if growth has 46 columns then you can replace `2:46` by more concise `-1`.

Comment: That is probably because doing `colnames(growth[, 2:46]) <- ...` you create a subset of your original `data.frame`, than you create a character vector with your `substring()` call, and after that you assign this character vector to the earlier created subset of `growth`. So the output is a character vector of (desired) names. If you enclose your code into parenthesis you will see something like: `[1] "2"  "3"  "4"..."45" "46"`. However, I believe someone with better knowledge of R would explain it better than me, or would correct me if I got it wrong.