# Converting a data frame to a numerical data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Here's a data frame I'm working with:

```
c1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
c2 = c('d', 'a', 'd', 'c')
c3 = c('a', 'c', 'd', 'b')
c4 = c('a', 'c', 'b', 'd')
df = data.frame(c1, c2, c3, c4)

c1    c2    c3    c4
a     d     a     a
b     a     c     c
c     d     d     b
d     c     b     d
```

I would like to convert using this scale: a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4. 
So that I get something like this:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
  1  4  1  1
  2  1  3  3
  3  4  4  2
  4  3  2  4
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
for(i in colnames(df)){
    df$i = gsub("a", 1, df$i)
    df$i = gsub("b", 2, df$i)
    df$i = gsub("c", 3, df$i)
    df$i = gsub("d", 4, df$i)
 }
```

But it doesn't work. Should I use gsub here, or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: similar to the answer below, if your key wasn't sequential, you could make your own  `key <- c('a'='1', 'b'='2', 'c'='3', 'd'='4'); df[] <- key[as.matrix(df)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this in a couple of ways.  One way is to convert the `data.frame` to `matrix` and then `match` those with `unique` elements in the dataset. i.e. in this case `letters[1:4]`.  But the result will be a vector.  We can convert it to the same `dimensions` of original dataset by specifying the `dim` as the `dim(df)` ie. `dim<-(..., dim(df)`.  Also please check [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449366/levels-what-sorcery-is-this) to find out more details about the assignment.

```
df2 <- df
df2[] <- `dim<-`(match(as.matrix(df), letters[1:4]), dim(df))
df2
#  c1 c2 c3 c4
#1  1  4  1  1
#2  2  1  3  3
#3  3  4  4  2
#4  4  3  2  4
```

The above code can be split into separate lines:

```
v1 <- match(as.matrix(df), letters[1:4])
df2[] <- `dim<-`(v1, dim(df))
```

or

```
df2[] <- matrix(v1, ncol=ncol(df), row=nrow(df))
```

Another option is to convert the dataset columns to `factor` with levels specified as unique values of dataset and then convert it to `numeric` by `as.numeric`.  This can be done in a `loop` using `lapply`

```
df2[] <-lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(factor(x, levels=letters[1:4])))
```

Comment: Really nice, and more or less exactly what I had in mind, but doing so in one line feels a little like showing off, don't you think? :) Separating it out and explaining a little bit I'm sure would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @akrun, what does `dim<-` do here? is this a built in function for r?

Comment: @akrun, never mind, for some reason there are these ` that show up surrounding dim. That's why I was wondering if I have ever seen such a thing.

Comment: @jasonadams  I had seen others using this way.  But, if you are uncomfortable using that, the second one is standard ie. using the `matrix` call.

Comment: Thanks, @akrun, that's nice. For anyone interested in the `dim<-` sorcery (as it's called in this answer), see this great question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10449366/210673

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for providing the link.  I will add this link to the post.