# What is the functional form of the assignment operator, [<-?

Tags: r

Is there a functional form of the assignment operator? I would like to be able to call assignment with lapply, and if that's a bad idea I'm curious anyways.

Edit:

This is a toy example, and obviously there are better ways to go about doing this:

Let's say I have a list of data.frames, dat, each corresponding to a one run of an experiment. I would like to be able to add a new column, "subject", and give it a sham-name. The way I was thinking of it was something like

```
lapply(1:3, function(x) assign(data.frame = dat[[x]], column="subject", value=x)
```

The output could either be a list of modified data frames, or the modification could be purely a side effect.

dput of list starting list

```
list(structure(list(V1 = c(-1.16664504687199, -0.429499924318301,  2.15470735901367, -0.287839633854442, -0.850578353982526, 0.211636723222015,  -0.184714165752958, -0.773553182015158, 0.801811848828454, 1.39420292299319 ), V2 = c(-0.00828185523886259, -0.0215669898046275, 0.743065397283645,  -0.0268464140141802, 0.168027242784788, -0.602901928341917, 0.0740511186398372,  0.180307494696194, 0.131160421341309, -0.924995634374182)), .Names = c("V1",  "V2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(     V1 = c(1.81912921386885, 1.17011641727415, 0.692247839769473,      0.0323050362633069, 1.35816977313292, -0.437475434344363,      -0.270255715332778, 0.96140963297774, 0.914691132220417,      -1.8014509598977), V2 = c(1.45082316226241, 2.05135744606495,      -0.787250759618171, 0.288104852581324, -0.376868533959846,      0.531872044490353, -0.750375220117567, -0.459592764008714,      0.991667163481123, 1.31280356980115)), .Names = c("V1", "V2" ), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(     V1 = c(0.528912899341174, 0.464615157920766, -0.184211714281637,      0.526909095449027, -0.371529800682086, -0.483772861751781,      -2.02134822661341, -1.30841566046747, -0.738493559993166,      -0.221463545903242), V2 = c(-1.44732101816006, -0.161730785376045,      1.06294520132753, 1.22680614207705, -0.721565979363022, -0.438309438404104,      -0.0243401435910825, 0.624227513999603, 0.276605218579759,      -0.965640602482051)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA,  -10L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: can you give an example (doesn't have to be working, obviously) of the call and the output you'd expect?

Comment: I agree with @hrbrmstr, because maybe there is a misunderstanding. Do you mean assign function/operator or replacement functions?

Comment: The replacement operator is just `\`[<-\`` but that doesn't change the value of the variable. `a<-1:3; \`[<-\`(a,1,5)`. But it's unclear exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: There are various R functions that might be called when you use `[<-`. You can see their names by typing `methods("[<-")`

Comment: This related answer explains replacement functions and how they can be called in this way. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10491881/210673

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I don't get it but as stated in "The Art of R programming":

> Any assignment statement in which the left side is not just an
>   identifier (meaning a variable name) is considered a replacement
>   function.

and so in fact you can always translate this:

```
names(x) <- c("a","b","ab")
```

to this:

```
x <- "names<-"(x,value=c("a","b","ab"))
```

the general rule is just `"function_name<-"(<object>, value = c(...))`

### Edit to the comment:

It works with the `"` too:

```
> x <- c(1:3)
> x
[1] 1 2 3
> names(x) <- c("a","b","ab")
> x
 a  b ab 
 1  2  3 
> x
 a  b ab 
 1  2  3 
> x <- c(1:3)
> x
[1] 1 2 3
> x <- "names<-"(x,value=c("a","b","ab"))
> x
 a  b ab 
 1  2  3
```

Comment: Sweet. The call I ended up using was 
    tmp = lapply(1:3, function(x) `[<-.data.frame`(dat[[3]], "subject", value=x))

Comment: One note: you have to backtick the operator to get it to act like a function, not use quotes.

Answer (score 3):

There is the `assign` function. I don't see any problems with using it but you have to be aware of what environment you want to assign to. See the help `?assign` for syntax.

Read this chapter carefully to understand the ins and outs of environments in detail.  http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I think that the OP wanted to know the replacement functions and not the assignment one. But I might be wrong of course.

Comment: He actually uses both terms, replacement operator in the title, and assignment operator in the text.

Comment: Yeah, I'm being a bit inconsistent. I'm curious about both, but the specific example I had in mind was assignment.