# How left assignment functions work?

Tags: r

I just learned a new way to use `'length<-'` in an apply function
something like:

```
l<- list(c(1,1,2,2,2),c(1,2),c(1,2,2,2),c(1,2,2))
sapply(l, `length<-`, 6)
```

creates a 4x6 matrix,

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    2    2    2
[3,]    2   NA    2    2
[4,]    2   NA    2   NA
[5,]    2   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

that is cool by itself. However I realized that

```
`length<-`(l[[1]],6)
```

will not change `l[[1]]`, so that

```
lapply(l, `length<-`, 6)
```

will not change `l`.

I would like to know if that is always the case for every single function that accepts a value assigned to it, such as `'dim<-'`, `'attr<-'`, etc. If so, is that a behaviour codified in the R parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length(x) <- 6` does not just do `"length<-"(x, 6)` but `x <- "length<-"(x, 6)`.  This is how lhs functions work in R.  See the first answer in [`levels<-`( What sorcery is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449366/levels-what-sorcery-is-this)

In your first example `sapply` creates a new matrix which you display us.  In the second example `"length<-"` creates a new vector of length 6 but that will not be assigned to any name.