# Paste together two data tables in R

Tags: r, data.table

How can I paste the values of two R data tables together?

Example:

```r
A <- data.table(matrix(LETTERS[1:4], 2))
a <- data.table(matrix(letters[1:4], 2))
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```r
Aa <- paste0DataTable(A, a)
> Aa
    V1  V2
1:  Aa  Cc
2:  Bb  Dd
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R paste matrix cells together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588962/r-paste-matrix-cells-together)

Comment: Try `mapply(paste0, A, a)`