# convert one factor to another in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
division | category
  A      |    tools
  A      |    work
  B      |    tools
  B      |    TOOLS
```

both columns are factor variables.
how do I convert TOOLS to tools?

I tried

```
df$category <- as.character(df$category)
df$category <- lapply(df$category, function(x) { tolower(x) } )
df$category <- as.factor(df$category)
```

but then for the last command I get:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that you've tried to factor a list, although not in those words.  It is triggered because you used `lapply()`, which returns a list. And in this situation `as.factor()` calls `factor()`, which in turn calls `sort.list()` here:

```
## from factor()
if (missing(levels)) {
    y <- unique(x, nmax = nmax)
    ind <- sort.list(y)
    ...
}
```

which is where the error occurs.

```
as.factor(list(1, 2))
# Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
# Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Long story short, you can use `tolower()` without `lapply()`, as it is vectorized and does the character coercion for you.

```
df$category <- factor(tolower(df$category))
df
#   division category
# 1        A    tools
# 2        A     work
# 3        B    tools
# 4        B    tools
```

Comment: Also, a more specific solution for `TOOLS` could be `factor(gsub("TOOLS", "tools", df$category, fixed = TRUE))`

Comment: And also `df$category[df$category == "TOOLS"] <- "tools"` as well, and then drop the unused level

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181753/grouping-factor-levels-in-an-r-data-table) question of mine or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410108/cleaning-up-factor-levels-collapsing-multiple-levels-labels) related question for how to group factors more generally

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use lapply. This worked for me.

```
division=c("a","a","b","b")
category=c("tools","work","tools","TOOLS")

df=data.frame(division,category)
df$category=tolower(df$category)

> as.factor(df$category)
[1] tools work  tools tools
```