# Best way to replace a lengthy ifelse structure in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
df = data.frame(Code=seq(80,105,1))
```

I need to add another column `tCode` that gets calculated from `Code` column. `Code` has a wide range of values. For each given range, I need to have a specific value for `tCode`. I can't use `cut` function for example for this task. The range and the expected outcome are given to me. 
I can only think of this lengthy `ifelse` structure:

```
  df$tCode = ifelse(df$Code > 102, 81, 
                            ifelse(df$Code %in% seq(101,102,1),80,
                                   ifelse(df$Code %in% seq(99,100,1),79,
                                          ifelse(df$Code %in% seq(97,89,1),78,
                                                 ifelse(df$Code %in% seq(95,96,1),77,
                                                        ifelse(df$Code %in% seq(92,94,1),76,
                                                               ifelse(df$Code %in% seq(90,91,1),75,
                                                                      ifelse(df$Code %in% seq(88,89,1),74,
                                                                             ifelse(df$Code %in% seq(86,87,1),73,
                                                                                    ifelse(df$Code %in% seq(84,85,1),72,
                                                                                           ifelse(df$Code %in% seq(82,83,1),71,
                                                                                                  ifelse(df$Code %in% seq(80,81,1),70,1))))))))))))
```

I don't feel that this is the best way to solve this problem. Are there better suggestions?.

Comment: You're doing recursion by hand. Represent the transformation you're making as a function.

Comment: Perhaps see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181753/grouping-factor-levels-in-an-r-data-table) question of mine for more options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Come up with a matching table and merge.

I'll do the first couple statements for brevity, hopefully you get the point:

```
library(data.table); setDT(df)

match_table <- 
  data.table(Code = c(89:102),
             tCode = c(rep(78, 9), 79, 79, 80, 80))

df[match.table, tCode := tCode, on = "Code"]
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense @MichaelChirico. Thanks