# if else and divide into categories in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to divide a column of number into 6 equal categories if the number is larger than 0.

This is have tried

```
if (nost13$actsum > 0) nost13$actclass2 <- as.factor( as.numeric( cut(nost13$actsum ,6)))
else 0
```

Not working though...

What is wrong?

Comment: The first thing that is wrong is the use of `if`. In R it does not act on vectors as the warning message should have told you.

Comment: ok :-) Then how would it be done then??

Comment: (1) see `?ifelse`; (2) if that doesn't answer your question, can you please include data that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to replace a lengthy ifelse structure in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390967/best-way-to-replace-a-lengthy-ifelse-structure-in-r)

Comment: ill look into ifelse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this untested stab at an answer. Tested solutions can be provided if you first provide a data object. There's also ambiguity about what an "equal category" might be. Equal counts? Or equal span? This answers the equal span which is what `cut` would deliver.

```
 nost13$actclass2 <- ifelse(nost13$actsum > 0,
                                 cut(nost13$actsum ,6), 0)
```

I suspect the coercion to numeric will occur inside `ifelse`. Your code would have attempted to append 0's to factors which would have ended in tears. If you wnat this to be a factor with levels "0"-"6" then wrap the entire `ifelse(....)` in `factor(.)`.

Here's some lightweight testing:

```
 actclass2 <- ifelse(-100:100 > 0,
                                  cut(-100:100 ,6), 0)
 table(actclass2)
#------------
actclass2
  0   4   5   6 
101  33  33  34
```

So depending on the distribution of values, you might not have gotten exactly what you wanted. This shows a modification of that strategy that will probably be more pleasing:

```
> vals <- -100:100
> splits <- seq(min(vals[vals>0]),max(vals[vals>0]), length=8)[-8]
> actclass2 <- ifelse(vals > 0,
+                           cut(vals ,breaks=splits ), 0)
> table(actclass2)
actclass2
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6 
101  14  14  14  14  14  14
```

Need a sequence of length = 8 to get 6 intervals with cut, since the max value was discarded and need 7 boundaries to generate 6 intervals. After going through this I'm thinking that the findInterval function would produce a clearer path to success.

```
> table( findInterval( vals, c(-Inf, 0, splits[-1], Inf) ))

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
100  16  14  14  14  14  14  15
```

`findInterval` has intervals closed on the left versus `cut` whose default is closed on the right.