# Nested ifelse: improved syntax

Tags: r, if-statement, syntax, nested, vectorization

### Description

**ifelse()**  function allows to filter the values in a vector through a series of tests, each of them producing different actions in case of a positive result. For instance, let `xx` be a data.frame, as follows:

```
xx <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,1,3), b=1:4)
xx
```

> a b
>   1 1
>   2 2
>   1 3
>   3 4

Suppose that you want to create a new column, **c**, from column **b**, but depending on the values in column **a** in the following way:

For each row,

- if the value in column **a** is 1, the value in column **c**, is the same value in column **b**.
- if the value in column **a** is 2, the value in column **c**, is 100 times the value in column **b**.
- in any other case, the value in column **c** is the negative of the value in column **b**.

Using **ifelse()**, a solution could be:

```
xx$c <- ifelse(xx$a==1, xx$b, 
               ifelse(xx$a==2, xx$b*100,
                      -xx$b))
xx
```

> a b c
>   1 1 1
>   2 2 200
>   1 3  3
>   3 4 -4

### Problem 1

An aesthetic problem arises when the number of tests increases, say, four tests:

```
xx$c <- ifelse(xx$a==1, xx$b, 
           ifelse(xx$a==2, xx$b*100,
                  ifelse(xx$a==3, ...,
                         ifelse(xx$a==4, ...,
                                ...))))
```

I found partial solution to the problem in [this page](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-wrapper-around-nested-ifelse/), which consists in the definition of the functions **if.else_(), i_(), e_()**, as follows:

```
library(lazyeval)
i_ <- function(if_stat, then) {
    if_stat <- lazyeval::expr_text(if_stat)
    then    <- lazyeval::expr_text(then)
    sprintf("ifelse(%s, %s, ", if_stat, then)
}

e_ <- function(else_ret) {
    else_ret <- lazyeval::expr_text(else_ret)
    else_ret
}

if.else_ <- function(...) {
    args <- list(...)

    for (i in 1:(length(args) - 1) ) {
        if (substr(args[[i]], 1, 6) != "ifelse") {
            stop("All but the last argument, need to be if.then_ functions.", call. = FALSE)
        }
    }
    if (substr(args[[length(args)]], 1, 6) == "ifelse"){
        stop("Last argument needs to be an else_ function.", call. = FALSE)
    }
    args$final <- paste(rep(')', length(args) - 1), collapse = '')
    eval_string <- do.call('paste', args)
    eval(parse(text = eval_string))
}
```

In this way, the problem given in the **Description**, can be rewritten as follows:

```
xx <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,1,3), b=1:4)
xx$c <- if.else_(
    i_(xx$a==1, xx$b),
    i_(xx$a==2, xx$b*100),
    e_(-xx$b)
) 
xx
```

> a b c
>   1 1 1
>   2 2 200
>   1 3  3
>   3 4 -4

And the code for the four tests will simply be:

```
xx$c <- if.else_(
    i_(xx$a==1, xx$b),
    i_(xx$a==2, xx$b*100),
    i_(xx$a==3, ...), # dots meaning actions for xx$a==3
    i_(xx$a==4, ...), # dots meaning actions for xx$a==4
    e_(...)           # dots meaning actions for any other case
)
```

### Problem 2 & Question

The given code apparently solves the problem. Then, I wrote the following test function:

```
test.ie <- function() {
    dd <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,1,3), b=1:4)
    if.else_(
        i_(dd$a==1, dd$b),
        i_(dd$a==2, dd$b*100),
        e_(-dd$b)
    ) # it should give c(1, 200, 3, -4)
}
```

When I tried the test:

```
 test.ie()
```

it spit the following error message:

> Error in ifelse(dd$a == 1, dd$b, ifelse(dd$a == 2, dd$b * 100, -dd$b)) :
>    object 'dd' not found

#### Question

Since the **if.else_()** syntactic constructor is not supposed to run only from the console, is there a way for it to 'know' the variables from the function that calls it?

#### Note

In "[Best way to replace a lengthy ifelse structure in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390967/best-way-to-replace-a-lengthy-ifelse-structure-in-r)", a similar problem was posted. However, the given solution there focuses on building the table's new column with the given **constant** output values (the "then" or "else" slots of the ifelse() function), whereas my case addresses a syntactic problem in which the "then" or "else" slots can even be expressions in terms of other data.frame elements or variables.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36391018/3576984

Comment: Rather than debugging this eval/parse nonsense, why not use something like `case_when` from the `dplyr` library. Or you can change the function to eval in the `parent frame()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to replace a lengthy ifelse structure in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390967/best-way-to-replace-a-lengthy-ifelse-structure-in-r)

Comment: `xx$b * c(-1,1,100,1)[interaction(xx$a==1, xx$a==2)]` - there's always ways and means. This may not be adaptable to every circumstance, but these kind of things are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With full respect to the OP's remarkable effort to improve nested `ifelse()`, I prefer a different approach which I believe is easy to write, concise, maintainable and fast:

```
xx <- data.frame(a=c(1L,2L,1L,3L), b=1:4)

library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table, and set the default first
setDT(xx)[, c:= -b]
xx[a == 1L, c := b]        # 1st special case
xx[a == 2L, c := 100L*b]   # 2nd special case, note use of integer 100L
# xx[a == 3L, c := ...]    # other cases
# xx[a == 4L, c := ...]
#...

xx
#   a b   c
#1: 1 1   1
#2: 2 2 200
#3: 1 3   3
#4: 3 4  -4
```

Note that for the 2nd special case `b` is multiplied by the integer constant `100L` to make sure that the right hand sides are all of type integer in order to avoid type conversion to double.

---

**Edit 2:** This can also be written in an even more concise (but still maintainable) way as a *one-liner*:

```
setDT(xx)[, c:= -b][a == 1L, c := b][a == 2L, c := 100*b][]
```

`data.table` chaining works here, because `c` is updated *in place* so that subsequent expressions are acting on *all* rows of `xx` even if the previous expression was a selective update of a subset of rows.

---

**Edit 1:** This approach can be implemented with base R as well:

```
xx <- data.frame(a=c(1L,2L,1L,3L), b=1:4)

xx$c <- -xx$b
idx <- xx$a == 1L; xx$c[idx] <- xx$b[idx]
idx <- xx$a == 2L; xx$c[idx] <- 100 * xx$b[idx]

xx
#  a b   c
#1 1 1   1
#2 2 2 200
#3 1 3   3
#4 3 4  -4
```

Comment: Great! When I first approached the nested ifelse () subject, it was because I was looking for some simple syntactic construction similar to the C ++ switch () {case: ...} construct. This answer meets my expectations: it is the most simple, understandable, and, I think, the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: @JulioSergio First, I was unsure whether I should post this suggestion which seems to be _way off_ of your question. But thanks to your feedback, I'm glad I did. That's very encouraging!

Comment: Just a note on priority when cases overlap (i.e., multiple cases match): this solution requires cases to be listed in the *opposite* order to the `ifelse` or `case_when`. That is, this ultimately assigns the last match whereas the others assign the first match.

Answer (score 10):

I think you can use [`dplyr::case_when`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) inside [`dplyr::mutate`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) to achieve this.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a=c(1,2,1,3), b=1:4)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    foo = case_when(
      .$a == 1 ~ .$b,
      .$a == 2 ~ .$b * 100L,
      TRUE   ~ .$b * -1L
    )
  )

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>       a     b   foo
#>   <dbl> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     2     2   200
#> 3     1     3     3
#> 4     3     4    -4
```

In the upcoming relase of `dplyr 0.6.0` you won't need to use the akward work-around of `.$`, and you can just use:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(
    foo = case_when(
      a == 1 ~ b,
      a == 2 ~ b * 100L,
      TRUE   ~ b * -1L
    )
  )
```

Comment: Please, can you explain what the reason is to wrap all right hand side expressions separately in `as.double()`?

Comment: Yes, that's because `case_when` is strict about type, and so for the first line `b` is an integer, but `b * 100` becomes a double, and so everything should be double. The strictness in intended to make the output type more predictable, and makes it somewhat faster.

Comment: I see, good point. Thanks for hinting. Perhaps, explicit type conversion to double could be avoided if you multiply with the integer constant `100L` to keep the RHS all integer? I just have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely true, (I'll update my answer for that). I just was thinking in your real use case it might not be all integer and then it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account [MrFlick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick) advice, I re-coded the **if.else_()** function as follows:

```
if.else_ <- function(...) {
    args <- list(...)

    for (i in 1:(length(args) - 1) ) {
        if (substr(args[[i]], 1, 6) != "ifelse") {
            stop("All but the last argument, need to be if.then_ functions.", call. = FALSE)
        }
    }
    if (substr(args[[length(args)]], 1, 6) == "ifelse"){
        stop("Last argument needs to be an else_ function.", call. = FALSE)
    }
    args$final <- paste(rep(')', length(args) - 1), collapse = '')
    eval_string <- do.call('paste', args)
    eval(parse(text = eval_string), envir = parent.frame())
}
```

Now the **test.ie()** function runs properly

```
test.ie()
```

> [1]   1 200   3  -4