# Collapse multiple level factors within dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with lots of variables and would like to reformat some of the variables as factors with more numerical values corresponding to the same (ordered) factor level. See the following example:

```r
mydf <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:2,10,replace=TRUE)))
mydf[6, ] <- c(NA, NA, 2)
names(mydf) <- c("med", "fed", "id")

mydf
   med fed id
1    2   2  1
2    0   0  0
3    0   1  0
4    0   1  2
5    1   0  2
6   NA  NA  2
7    0   1  2
8    0   2  0
9    0   0  2
10   2   2  2
```

I would like to reformat the variables `med` and `fed` as factors with two levels: 0 - "foo", 1,2 - "bar" where "foo" < "bar". I know I can do it separately for the variables as hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410108/cleaning-up-factor-levels-collapsing-multiple-levels-labels):

```r
mydf$med <- `levels<-`(factor(mydf$med, ordered=TRUE), list("foo"=0, "bar"=c(1,2)))
mydf$fed <- `levels<-`(factor(mydf$fed, ordered=TRUE), list("foo"=0, "bar"=c(1,2)))

mydf
    med  fed id
1   bar  bar  1
2   foo  foo  0
3   foo  bar  0
4   foo  bar  2
5   bar  foo  2
6  <NA> <NA>  2
7   foo  bar  2
8   foo  bar  0
9   foo  foo  2
10  bar  bar  2 

table(mydf$med)
foo bar 
  6   3
```

Is there a way to do it at once for each variable that matches some pattern? E.g. using `dplyr` somewhat like

```r
mydf %>% mutate_each(funs(???), matches("ed$"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David Arenburg pointed out, the solution is kind of obvious, using `dplyr` and the hint for the one-variable case (with the simpler, multi-line formulation).

```r
library(dplyr)
myfunc <- function(x) {
    x <- factor(x, ordered=TRUE)
    levels(x) <- list("foo"=0, "bar"=c(1,2))
    x
}

mydf <- mydf %>% mutate_each(funs(myfunc), matches("ed$"))
mydf
    med  fed id
1   bar  bar  1
2   foo  foo  0
3   foo  bar  0
4   foo  bar  2
5   bar  foo  2
6  <NA> <NA>  2
7   foo  bar  2
8   foo  bar  0
9   foo  foo  2
10  bar  bar  2 

table(mydf$med)
foo bar 
  6   3
```