# R adding a column to a data frame after comparing string value within it

Tags: r, string

Edited to ask a better question:

```
libary("ggplot2)
data("diamonds")
diamonds_small <- diamonds[1:5000, ]
cutnewfunc <- function(x){
 ifelse(x == c("Ideal", "Premium", "Very Good", "Good", "Fair"), c("Above Average", "Above Average", "Very Good", "Below Average", "Below Average"), "Default")
}
cutvect = as.vector(diamonds_small$cut)
newdiamonds = cutnewfunc(cutvect)
newdiamonds
```

Result:
    [1] "Above Average" "Above Average" "Default"       "Default"       "Default"       "Default"       "Default"
   [8] "Very Good"     "Default"       "Default"       "Default"       "Default"       "Default"       "Default"
  [15] "Default"       "Default"       "Default"       "Default"       "Below Average" "Default"       "Default"

As you can see, there are a lot of "Default" values, which shouldn't be happening, as calling cutvect will result in:

```
[1] "Ideal"     "Premium"   "Good"      "Premium"   "Good"      "Very Good" "Very Good" "Very Good" "Fair"
```

[10] "Very Good" "Good"      "Ideal"     "Premium"   "Ideal"     "Premium"   "Premium"   "Ideal"     "Good"
  [19] "Good"      "Very Good" "Good"      "Very Good" "Very Good" "Very Good" "Very Good" "Very Good" "Premium"

How would I go about comparing every value, and not result in "default"?

Thank you!

---

I need to compare a string value inside a data frame, generate result accordingly, and add it to a new column in the data frame.

I think I'll need to: 1. take the column with the parameter strings and form a vector,
2. Compare the strings and form a new vector with the result,
3. add it the result vector as a new column to the original data frame.

The comparing strings bit is not working for me.

The question says I need to use the 'ifelse' function, but comparing string result in 'only applicable to logical or numeric values' error.

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please save the RStudio tag for problems specific to that editor - for example if you have R code that runs fine in the R Gui or command line but doesn't run in RStudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
x == c("Ideal", "Premium", "Very Good", "Good", "Fair")
```

`==` doesn't work the way you seem to think... We can try some simple cases to see what it does:

```
> x = "Premium"
> x == c("Ideal", "Premium", "Very Good", "Good", "Fair")
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE


> x = c("Premium", "Fair")
> x == c("Ideal", "Premium", "Very Good", "Good", "Fair")
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Warning message:
In x == c("Ideal", "Premium", "Very Good", "Good", "Fair") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
## Notice this result is ALL FALSE!


> x = rep("Premium", 10)
> x == c("Ideal", "Premium", "Very Good", "Good", "Fair")
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

When we do `x == y`, if `x` and `y` are the same length the comparison will be *pairwise*: the first element of x compared to the first of y, the second of x compared to the second of y, etc. If one of `x` or `y` is longer than the other, the shorter one will be repeated until the lengths are equal, but the comparison is always *pairwise*.

A full answer on better ways to do combine factor levels is here:
 [Cleaning up factor levels (collapsing multiple levels/labels)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19410108/903061). The best ways do not use `ifelse`. But if you must use `ifelse`, do it like this:

```
cutnewfunc <- function(x){
  ifelse(x %in% c("Ideal", "Premium"), "Above Average",
    ifelse(x %in% c("Very Good"), "Very Good"), "Default"))
}
```

I didn't write it out completely because it sounds like it's homework. I'll let you fill in the rest.

Comment: Thank you so much Gregor! It worked beautifully. I'll be sure to ask better questions from now on ;)P