# Combining several class into one class

Tags: r

I am very new to R and am looking for advice. I have an output of Olympic Data that has 4 classes (Gold, Silver, Bronze, NoMedal). I would like to know if there is a function in R that will combine 3 of those classes (Gold, Silver, Bronze) into one class (Medal) so that I can use the ROSE function to balance the dataset. Anyone know a function that will do this?

Current Output (4 classes): Gold, Silver, Bronze, NoMedal

Desired Output (2 classes): Medal, NoMedal

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Cleaning, collapsing multiple factor levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410108/cleaning-up-factor-levels-collapsing-multiple-levels-labels). Hope that helps you answer your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cleaning up factor levels (collapsing multiple levels/labels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410108/cleaning-up-factor-levels-collapsing-multiple-levels-labels)