# How can I combine 2 levels in a variable in R

Tags: r

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
> levels(Cambodia$`Income changed after 2020`)
[1] "Yes, I lost a total of income"        "Yes, I lost a partial of income"      "No, I earn the same amount of income"
[4] "Yes, I earn more income"
```

I want to combine `"Yes, I earn more income"` and `"No, I earn the same amount of income"` to form a new level in the variable, so that it would look like:

```
> levels(Cambodia$`Income changed after 2020`)
[1] "Yes, I lost a total of income"        "Yes, I lost a partial of income"      "No income loss"
```

I tried doing this but it did not work:

```
library(forcats)
Cambodia %>% fct_collapse(Cambodia$`Income changed after 2020` == c("Yes, I earn more income","No, I earn the same amount of income"))
```

Comment: Your `fct_collapse` line didn't work because you passed what seems to be a data frame (can't tell without any of your data) to a function that expects a vector, and then tried to create a level with the name "Cambodia$`Income changed after 2020`", which doesn't make a lot of sense, and used a comparison (`==`) instead of an assignment (`=`). I'd recommend reading through the docs of functions like this first to see how they're used

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410108/cleaning-up-factor-levels-collapsing-multiple-levels-labels

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
levels(Cambodia$`Income changed after 2020`)[levels(Cambodia$`Income changed after 2020`)%in%c("Yes, I earn more income","No, I earn the same amount of income")] <- "no income change"
```