# Collapsing categorieal levels R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data (s_data).

```
levels(as.factor(s_data$education))

"10th"          "11th"         "12th"         "1st-4th"     
"5th-6th"      "7th-8th"      "9th"          "Assoc-acdm"    
"Assoc-voc"    "Bachelors"    "Doctorate"    "HS-grad"     
"Masters"      "Preschool"    "Prof-school"  "Some-college"
```

I am trying to collapse samples into one category. For example, "Preschool" and "1st-4th" would be one category, kids.  I have tried a couple of approaches with no success.

```
s_data$education <- case_when(data$education %in% c("1st-4th", "5th-6th", "7th-8th",
                                      "9th","Preschool") ~ "kids") #s_data is an adjusted version of data
```

This approach tries to replace each row and doesn't yield anything but an error.

I have tried our teacher's approach and when I tried to plot the new data, it did not consist the new category ("kids") at all.

```
levels(as.factor(s_data$education)) <- c("10th","11th,", "kids", "kids", "kids","7th-8th", "9th", "Assoc-acdm",
                                         "Assoc-voc", "Bachelors","Doctorate","HS-grad", "Masters","kids", "Prof-school",
                                         "Some-college")
```

Do you have ideas how can I collapse these levels into one category?

Thank you!

Comment: First, *"doesn't yield anything but an error"* would do better if you included the error. Second, your `case_when` is incomplete: you check for one membership and reassign based on it, and then discard everything else in `education`; it is not doing a piecewise replacement, I suggest you read its documentation to understand what it is doing. Third, I don't know if it is originally a `factor` or if your `levels` call was merely to show all unique values. Can you provide an unambiguous sample of that vector? Perhaps `dput(s_data$education)` (or a subset of it if it is a large dataset).

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, education, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,  : 
  replacement has 48842 rows, data has 48182

levels calls was merely to show all unique values. 
dput(s_data$education) - provides every unique value of each row. 

What I need to do is to create a new category which would overwrite categories I wish to collapse. 

I hope I am more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Because you keep calling `as.factor` (and we don't have your data, large as it may be), it is not clear to me if your `s_data$education` is class `character` or `factor`.

- if `is.character(s_data$education)`, then

  ```r
  educ <- c("10th", "11th", "12th", "1st-4th", "5th-6th", "7th-8th", "9th", "Assoc-acdm", "Assoc-voc", "Bachelors", "Doctorate", "HS-grad", "Masters", "Preschool", "Prof-school", "Some-college")
  educ[educ %in% c("9th", "10th", "11th", "12th")] <- "HS"
  educ
  #  [1] "HS"           "HS"           "HS"           "1st-4th"      "5th-6th"      "7th-8th"      "HS"          
  #  [8] "Assoc-acdm"   "Assoc-voc"    "Bachelors"    "Doctorate"    "HS-grad"      "Masters"      "Preschool"   
  # [15] "Prof-school"  "Some-college"
  ```
- if `is.factor(s_data$education)`, then make sure you pre-add the new levels (or make sure they are already present) and then reassign:

  ```r
  educ <- factor(c("10th", "11th", "12th", "1st-4th", "5th-6th", "7th-8th", "9th", "Assoc-acdm", "Assoc-voc", "Bachelors", "Doctorate", "HS-grad", "Masters", "Preschool", "Prof-school", "Some-college"))
  educ
  #  [1] 10th         11th         12th         1st-4th      5th-6th      7th-8th      9th          Assoc-acdm   Assoc-voc   
  # [10] Bachelors    Doctorate    HS-grad      Masters      Preschool    Prof-school  Some-college
  # 16 Levels: 10th 11th 12th 1st-4th 5th-6th 7th-8th 9th Assoc-acdm Assoc-voc Bachelors Doctorate HS-grad ... Some-college
  levels(educ)
  #  [1] "10th"         "11th"         "12th"         "1st-4th"      "5th-6th"      "7th-8th"      "9th"         
  #  [8] "Assoc-acdm"   "Assoc-voc"    "Bachelors"    "Doctorate"    "HS-grad"      "Masters"      "Preschool"   
  # [15] "Prof-school"  "Some-college"
  levels(educ) <- c("HS", levels(educ))
  educ[educ %in% c("9th", "10th", "11th", "12th")] <- "HS"
  educ
  #  [1] HS          HS          HS          HS          1st-4th     5th-6th     7th-8th     HS          Assoc-acdm 
  # [10] Assoc-voc   Bachelors   Doctorate   HS-grad     Masters     Preschool   Prof-school
  # 17 Levels: HS 10th 11th 12th 1st-4th 5th-6th 7th-8th 9th Assoc-acdm Assoc-voc Bachelors Doctorate HS-grad ... Some-college
  ```

  At some point, you may want/need to remove the now-absent levels from your data.

This might be facilitated with tidyverse's `forcats` package, see [Cleaning up factor levels (collapsing multiple levels/labels)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19410108/3358272) and [Grouping 2 levels of a factor in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9604001/3358272).